How to create Ubuntu arm64 docker container with gcc-multilib?
I have a working i386 cross-compilation build container and attempting to recreate the container as arm64 to remove the Rosetta overhead in Docker Desktop for Mac (macOS Sonoma on an M1 MacBookPro)
docker build -t linux-build.arm64 . is unable to resolve the last two packages gcc-multilib and g++-multilib
Here is my Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN dpkg --add-architecture amd64 && \
        apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y -o APT::Immediate-Configure=0 \
                libc6:amd64 \
                libncurses6:amd64 \
                libstdc++6:amd64 \
                build-essential \
                cmake \
                git \
                libncurses6 \
                libncurses-dev \
                libssl-dev \
                mercurial \
                texinfo \
                zip \
                default-jre \
                imagemagick \
                subversion \
                autoconf \
                automake \
                bison \
                scons \
                libglib2.0-dev \
                bc \
                mtools \
                u-boot-tools \
                flex \
                wget \
                cpio \
                dosfstools \
                libtool \
                rsync \
                device-tree-compiler \
                gettext \
                locales \
                graphviz \
                python3 \
                gcc-multilib \
                g++-multilib \
        && apt-get clean \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Any tips on resolving this or is this a lost cause?
